# React Native Time Picker Android component is rendering with white header

Tags: react-native

In my project, I'm using TimePickerAndroid from react-native. But when I run the app on my Android device, the date picker component shows with a white header, repeating the time selected. I don't know if this thing just appears in the development environment.

I'm using the same code of official react native documentation to show the date time picker

```
const { action, hour, minute } = await TimePickerAndroid.open({
        hour: 14,
        minute: 0,
        is24Hour: true,                
      })
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Is that part of the `TimePickerAndroid` component? Which android simulator are you running?

Comment: @bntzio I'm running on my own device. I'm talking about the header, inside the red rectangle area. It seems wrong because I've seen other apps which use time picker and this blank header, repeating every selection, doesn't exist. I've made this read rectangle area, just for helping.

Comment: I think it's just how the device works, some days ago I tried to use the `TimePickerAndroid` in an old device and tried the `spinner` mode and the device didn't support it, then tried in another device and it worked, so maybe it's just part of the device set-up for that particular component in that particular device.

Comment: I agree with @bntzio, I also get this header, then I used https://github.com/mmazzarolo/react-native-modal-datetime-picker

Comment: Thanks, @AnkushRishi I've tested this component in my project. However, I still have this issue. As btnzio said maybe the problem is the setup of the device itself.